# Inferring absolute continuity of summands from absolute continuity of sum

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have i.i.d. random variables $X_1, X_2$.

If $\text{Law}(X_1 + X_2)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, can we infer that each $X_i$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ also?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Doesn't the convolution formula _assume_ that $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ exist (equivalently that $X_1, X_2 \ll \lambda$)? I am trying to go the other way - essentially to infer that $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ exist from the fact $f_{X_1+X_2}$ does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false. The [second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/939990/215011) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/939958/215011) describes the construction of a singular measure $\mu$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ such that the convolution $\mu *\mu$ is absolutely continuous. So to find a counterexample to the claim, it suffices to take $X_1$ and $X_2$ iid with distribution $\mu$.